# Environment variables not being used when debugging through a Service Fabric project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

When creating an ASP.NET Core app an environment variable called `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` will be set for you and when debugging you will see that the `IHostingEnvironment` is set to `Development`.

The problem is that when I use the same project in a solution set up for Service Fabric the environment variables don't seem to get injected and `IHostingEnvironment` just returns "Production".

How can I resolve this?

Note: I've set a breakpoint in the startup class to observe the IHostingEnvironment variable.

Comment: What have you done with your Service Fabric app to set up the environment variable?  Are you doing a `SetupEntryPoint` as described here?  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-model/

Comment: I'm using the Service Fabric Template provided in Visual Studio. It correctly has the service entry xml preconfigured in the ServiceManifest. I was specifying the environment variable in launchsettings

Answer (score 13):

Reference for this answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-manage-multiple-environment-app-configuration

I ran into the same issue with the default template. The following is similar to Duncan's answer but with two important differences: 1) You will not have to change any template code within the service, and 2) the `IHostingEnvironment` will be properly set.

First, add the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to the `<CodePackage>` element of the `PackageRoot\ServiceManifest.xml` file of the application service:

```
<CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
  <EntryPoint>
    <ExeHost>
      <Program>MyService.exe</Program>
      <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
    </ExeHost>
  </EntryPoint>
  <EnvironmentVariables>
    <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value=""/>
  </EnvironmentVariables>
</CodePackage>
```

As in Duncan's response, there are two changes you'll make to the `ApplicationManifest.xml` of your Service Fabric Application project. First, setup a parameter (variable) so that it can be modified when the `ApplicationParameters` files are substituted based on the way you deploy the project. Then, add an `EnvironmentalOverrides` section to your `ServiceManifestImport` element. The results of the two additions will look something like this:

```
<Parameters>
  <Parameter Name="MyService_InstanceCount" DefaultValue="-1" />
  <Parameter Name="AspNetCoreEnvironment" DefaultValue="" />
</Parameters>

<ServiceManifestImport>
  <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="MyServicePkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
  <EnvironmentOverrides CodePackageRef="Code">
    <EnvironmentVariable Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="[AspNetCoreEnvironment]" />
  </EnvironmentOverrides>
</ServiceManifestImport>
```

Finally, you can add in the proper values in the individual `ApplicationParameters` files:

```
<Parameters>
  <Parameter Name="MyService_InstanceCount" Value="-1" />
  <Parameter Name="AspNetCoreEnvironment" Value="Development" />
</Parameters>
```

At this point, you can remove the variable from your service's Properties - Debug environmental variables.

Comment: Since `EnvironmentVariables` are a newer feature in Service Fabric, I think this is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into the same issue and was able to create a solution that worked for me.

If you look at your ASP.NET Core project, you should see a *Program.cs* file. At the bottom of it you should see the following interface implementation:

```
Task<string> ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
...
}
```

You're going to first want to change it to something like the following:

```
Task<string> ICommunicationListener.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var context = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext();
    var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint(_endpointName);
    var config = context.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
    var environment = config.Settings.Sections["Environment"].Parameters["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"].Value;

    var serverUrl = $"{endpoint.Protocol}://{FabricRuntime.GetNodeContext().IPAddressOrFQDN}:{endpoint.Port}";

    _webHost = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()
                                   .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                   .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                   .UseEnvironment(environment)
                                   .UseUrls(serverUrl)
                                   .Build();

    _webHost.Start();

    return Task.FromResult(serverUrl);
}
```

The key portion is the `.UseEnvironment(environment)` call, along with the supporting retrieval of the environment from the configuration. This will give ASP.NET Core the necessary information it needs to choose the environment.

Having done this, you'll obviously need to add the **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** setting to the config section. That looks like the following:

Under your ASP.NET Core project you'll find a directory called *PackageRoot/Config*. Inside of that there should be a *Settings.xml* file. Add the following code inside the `<Settings>` tag...

```
<Section Name="Environment">
  <Parameter Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="" />
</Section>
```

Next, you're going to want to look at the *ApplicationPackageRoot/ApplicationManifest.xml* file inside the actual **Service Fabric Project** (this is NOT the ASP.NET Core project). Two file changes are required.

1. Add the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT parameter inside the `<Parameters>` tag at the top of the file like so:

   ```
   <Parameter Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" DefaultValue="" />
   ```
2. Modify your `<ServiceManifestImport>` tag to include a `<ConfigOverrides>` section like so:

   ```
   <ConfigOverrides>
     <ConfigOverride Name="Config">
       <Settings>
         <Section Name="Environment">
           <Parameter Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="[ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT]" />
         </Section>
       </Settings>
     </ConfigOverride>
   </ConfigOverrides>
   ```

Finally, modify your *ApplicationParameters/Local.1Node.xml* and friends to contain the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` parameter:

```
<Parameter Name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" Value="Development" />
```

It's a lot of steps to add a freaking variable you can retrieve, but it does allow you a great deal of flexibility and follows the standard Service Fabric pattern to make deployments simple. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It looks like what you're describing is how to add settings in Service Fabric in general. Doing it this way will work, however there is a disconnect when you right click the project properties for the asp.net core project and change the value for the environment in the properties window.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan That's correct, there is indeed a disconnect. Forgive me if I've forgotten since I've typed this out, but the Project Properties path has simply no effect when running in Service Fabric, yeah? Maybe I'm crazy. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [answer from Duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39926795) worked for me, but there is a small variation for me, maybe due to the version of ASP.NET Core and Service Fabric I use.

I need to override the method `CreateServiceInstanceListeners` in my Web Stateless Service.
So that means I'll have this code:

```cs
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
            new WebListenerCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting WebListener on {url}");

                var environment = FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext()
                    ?.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config")
                    ?.Settings.Sections["Environment"]
                    ?.Parameters["ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT"]?.Value;

                return new WebHostBuilder().UseWebListener()
                    .ConfigureServices(
                        services => services
                            .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseEnvironment(environment)
                    .UseApplicationInsights()
                    .UseUrls(url)
                    .Build();
            }))
    };
}
```

Of course, you need to set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable as explained by Duncan.